# Spring Blazeds with Hibernate Session-In-View pattern

Tags: hibernate, session, serialization, blazeds

To implement session-in-view Hibernate pattern, i used my custom ServletFilter like that:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        // Starting a database transaction
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        // Continue the request 
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        // Committing the database transaction
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (StaleObjectStateException se) {
        // Some codes here
    }
}
```

It seems the transaction will be committed after the request is processed. But when we use Spring BlazeDS Integration to serialize the output from Flex, a problem occurs:

The BlazeDS serialize result object and all their child objects by using lazy fetch before transaction is committed (at line chain.doFilter). So many queries flood the database to get objects, sometimes it's never finish.

How can I resolve this problem? Have any configuration to limit the depth of serialization in BlazeDS?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you could have a look to [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229378): it comes with full lazy-loading support (see documentation [here](http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.2/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.remoting.html#remoting.jpa) and [here](http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.2/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.datamanagement.html)) and a great integration with the Spring framework (documentation [here](http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.2/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.spring.html)).